# Set width in % in context of the site

Tags: html, width

I want a page which looks same in all browsers, so what i was trying to do is setting css: `width= x%`.

Width is only working with the nearest wrapping tag, like `<div>...</div>`

How do I set `width` in context with the page/website or body?

I checked `position: ...` out, but thats not what i want

Code:

```
<table><tr><td>
            <a href="/lala">link</a>
                </td><td>
                    <strong>writing a book</strong>
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 45%" disabled>text 1</textarea>
                </td><td>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="50" disabled>text2</textarea>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your description is still pretty unclear. Do you have a code snippet or an end result of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a textarea. It shall be as big as 75% of the webpage. Its Inside a Table and a div (and more shit) .

Comment: Can you add your code? It's easy to review and fix if needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the % use vw (it stands for viewport width) and if you want the textarea to be 75% of the page you can set the textarea to 75vw.

[Check a demo here](https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/wEvWOE)

```
textarea{
    width: 75vw;
 }
```

Comment: works well - where did you get the knowlegde of `vw` ? - I never see this on tutorial pages or else.

Comment: I don't quite remember, it was a long time ago, but i mainly learnt from w3schools.com and mozilla developer network as those are the biggest resources and i go to them whenever i'm in need for something, i suggest you do the same they really help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an example, you could try setting the outer most container to 75%, then everything inside to 100%;

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions to this problem, but in your case an easy 75vw should do the trick.

Tip: Structure your code. It's not necessary but it helps for reading and rewriting.

Code:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/lala">link</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>writing a book</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 45%" disabled>text 1</textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="width:75vw" disabled>text2</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm formatting my code. As you see my tags are formatted after relevance. table formatting tags are (mostly) in one row so they dont confuse you and improving the information you can see per code page. You can do it your style if you want- Ill do it my way. I only wanted to say your comment is a duplicate of the already said answer. Have a nice day :P